# Type 'Collection' is not defined vb BC30002

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I am attempting to migrate a legacy vb.net application to .net standard and turn it into a nuget package. A good amount of it has been straight forward. I am currently hung up on this error caused by functions like this.

```
 Public Property ErrorMessages As Collection
        Get
            ErrorMessages = _errorMessages
        End Get
        Set(value As Collection)
            _errorMessages = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

If i import System.Collections.ObjectModelCollection(Of T) it is asking me for a type and i am unsure how to proceed. It turns my code into 
Collection(Of,) and expects a second argument. Has anyone faced this before? Do i use a different import statement or how is this dealt with in vb now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost certainly replace `Collection` with [`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), using the dictionary type from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Once again, this requires you to fill in the genetic type arguments `TKey` and `TValue` with the actual types. You need to figure out from context which type fits the collection. The value of `TKey` is probably `String` since that’s the only key type VB6’ collections properly support. And given the name (`ErrorMessages`), `TValue` is probably `String` as well.